# Change the number of displayed rows in jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Why the number of rows in `jquery datatable` (see the code below) is not set to 5? It is equal to 10 8as by default). Why `'iDisplayLength': 5` does not work here?

```
<script>
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON(
              'modules/getData.php',
        function(data) {
                  var oTable = $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
                        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
                        "aaSorting":[[3, "asc"]],
                        "bJQueryUI":true,
                        'iDisplayLength': 5,
                        'bLengthChange': false
                  });

                  oTable.fnDraw();

                  var list = data.flights;
                  var textToInsert = '';

                  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        aux = list[i];
                        textToInsert  += '<tr><td>';
                        textToInsert  += aux.Var1;                                                                  
                        textToInsert  += '</td> </tr>' ;

                    }
                  $('table#newspaper-b tbody').html(textToInsert);

              }
    );             
}         

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you intializing the datatable and then explicitly putting the data+html inside the table; Why not let the datatable handle that itself!

Comment: This is just a code piece. I need to make last 2 columns as input fields.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this. DataTables has built-in options that let you pull data from an AJAX source without trying to build it yourself. [Read the documentation](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) and customize it as needed:

```
function loadData() {
    var oTable = $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": 'modules/getData.php',
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [
                [3, "asc"]
            ],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            'iDisplayLength': 5,
            'bLengthChange': false
    });
};
```

To modify the table in some way after the data is loaded, you'll want to add the [`fnDrawCallback`](http://datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback) option:

```
 "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      // use jQuery to alter the content of certain cells
      $lastcell = $('#newspaper-b').find('tr').find('td:last');
      // manipulate it somehow
 }
```

Comment: In this case how can I define that some columns are input fields?

Comment: Updated answer. DataTables has an answer for just about everything, but there are so many options it can be hard to find what you need. Searching that site often turns up good results.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition, if you have previously been running/testing with `"bStateSave": true` and `iDisplayLength` not specified/at the default,  then the saved default for `iDisplayLength` will override any subsequent attempts to specify a new value, and you will still get 10 rows. Try emptying the cache, setting `"bStateSave": false`, specifying the `iDisplayLength` you want, and running again.

Answer (score 1):

This is definetely the easiest way I found:

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-button').click( function () {
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
        oSettings._iDisplayLength = 50;
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
});
```