# Indexing and Pagination

Tags: java, sql, oracle, indexing, pagination

I'm working on a Java-EE application and I'm filtering data to an html page as results from a key word search. There could be millions of records matching but I do not want to bring them all to the front end at once. But at the same time I need to know the number of records to do the pagination. Any ideas to accomplish this without making much network traffic? Data base is Oracle SQL 11g. Program is following struts 1.3 framework.

Comment: see here best example of implement datatable with servlet  and gson:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110665/limit-of-displaying-rows-in-datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer and it is working :)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, rownum r__
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CATEGORY.*,rownum FROM CATEGORY
        ORDER BY CATNAME ASC
    ) a
    WHERE rownum < ((pageno * pagesize) + 1 )
)
WHERE r__ >= (((pageno-1) * pagesize) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separate query to get rows count.

To apply pagination you can apply two different approaches:

1) Using ROWNUM:

```
select * 
from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
          a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
       from ( /*your_query_goes_here, 
              with order by*/ ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

:MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH is set to the last row of the result set to fetch—if you wanted 
:MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH is set to the first row of the result set to fetch

2) Using OFFSET FETCH:

```
select /*your_query_goes_here, with order by*/ fetch first :ROWS_PER_PAGE rows only
```

This will display the first N rows of the table (N=ROWS_PER_PAGE), in the order that was specified in the order by clause.

```
select /*your_query_goes_here, with order by*/ offset (:PAGE_NUMBER - 1) * :ROWS_PER_PAGE fetch first :ROWS_PER_PAGE rows only
```

This will offset into the table (in sorted order) and then fetch the next N rows of the table.

Comment: Thanks for answering..is offset fetch works in oracle 11g?

Comment: It's not available in 11g. It does work fine in 12c.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not send the whole query result to the client. You can do 2 queries:

1. get number of results, you can use `COUNT`
2. get the selected records e.g. page 1 - records from 1 to 30.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Isn't it taking the same time amount when getting the number of rows using count and when fetching all the records?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to create a method in your DAO that have as additional parameters start & end for example :

```
getCustomers(String keyword, int start,int end){
// get all customers
// sublist the result and get the data from start index to end index
// Or U cane use a query using LIMIT 
}
```

in your controller u ll do almost the same and u will give start and end parameters through POST or GET request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sublistedCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSublistedCustomers(@RequestParam("end") final String keyword,@RequestParam("start") final int start,@RequestParam("end") final int end){
 model.addAttribute("cutomersResult",yourDAO.getCustomers(keyword,start,end));
```

return "your-view";
    }

now you have a part of customers record on your jsp file and it s up to you to decide how to display this sublisted result :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the matching results in any page and the count of these results for **1 read**.

**Now,supposing a page will contains 10 items.**

You could get what you expect using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST (V_PAGE_NUMBER  IN NUMBER,
                                       V_RESULTS      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                       V_RESULT_COUNT OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  OPEN V_RESULTS FOR
  SELECT T.*
  FROM (SELECT T.*, ROWNUM ROWNUMBER
          FROM DJ_NSRXX T
         WHERE ROWNUM <= V_PAGE_NUMBER * 10) T
  WHERE ROWNUMBER > 10 * (V_PAGE_NUMBER - 1);

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_RESULT_COUNT FROM DJ_NSRXX;
END;
```

This procedure PROC_TEST accomplishes the task of paging and counting.