# javascript database multi criteria

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

ı have a code like

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#tbl-contact thead th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html(title+' <input type="text" class="col-search-input" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        });
        
        var table = $('#tbl-contact').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "pagingType": "numbers",
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "server.php",
            order: [[2, 'asc']],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: "_all",
                orderable: false
             }]
        });

        table.columns().every(function () {
            var table = this;
            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (table.search() !== this.value) {
                       table.search(this.value).draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I want use this code for list and filter my database but my database is realy huge like 9 or 10 gb. this code auto load all database to screen after filterin database . if ı use that my computer can error :D . ı want just load 10 item. how can ı do that ?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110665/limit-of-displaying-rows-in-datatables) of any help?

Comment: yes ı want load just 10 item or not load all database first time . how can ı connect this to any button ?