# customize "Show ## entriesSearch" for dataTable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi I have a following program. It works fine when iDisplayLength is 100. When we would like to change iDisplayLength as 200, the "Show ## entriesSearch" is empty. Is it be possible to customize "Show ## entriesSearch" in a way that **entries over 200 shows 'All'**. Any idea to do so?

```
function newVasDataTable() {
    var $newVasTable = $('#vas_table').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {"sSortDataType" : "dom-checkbox","aTargets" : [ 0 ]} ],
        "iDisplayLength" : 100
    });
    return $newVasTable;
}
```

Comment: How do I know ? But, I see the existing code use jQuery function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are working with an old version of datatables, so this may help you :

```
function newVasDataTable() {
    var $newVasTable = $('#vas_table').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {"sSortDataType" : "dom-checkbox","aTargets" : [ 0 ]} ],
        "iDisplayLength" : 100,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50,100, 200, "All"]]
    });
    return $newVasTable;
}
```

[More info can be found here](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html)

Comment: This is a good solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I partially found the customization here. [Limit of displaying rows in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110665/limit-of-displaying-rows-in-datatables) but it does not say how to show 'All' when over 200.

```
function newVasDataTable() {
    var $newVasTable = $('#vas_table').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {"sSortDataType" : "dom-checkbox","aTargets" : [ 0 ]} ],
        "iDisplayLength" : 200 ,
        "lengthMenu": [50, 100, 200],
        "pageLength": 200
    });
    return $newVasTable;
}
```