# Ajax datatable plugin paginate

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

i have this code, datatable plugin

```
$('#tbl_loket').createTable( {
    "ajax": "<?=site_url('penilaian/report/get_data')?>",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "date_in" },
        { "data": "nama" },
        { "data": "keterangan" },
        { "data": "sangat_puas" },
        { "data": "puas" },
        { "data": "tidak_puas" },
        { "data": "total" },
        { "data": "nilai" },
    ],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "paging": true,
} );
```

and this my table screenshot

[image: table screenshot]

question : how to change the number of items per page?

Comment: The question is unclear, are you asking how to change the number of items per page?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean @DaveL

Comment: i set 10 items per page, but there still show all data 15 row

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301286/change-the-number-of-displayed-rows-in-jquery-datatable)

Comment: but my table still show 15 items, not 10 items. cek this my table screenshot i.stack.imgur.com/YRrAF.png –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version, so you'll need to use:

```
$('#tbl_loket').createTable( {
   "ajax": "<?=site_url('penilaian/report/get_data')?>",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "date_in" },
        { "data": "nama" },
        { "data": "keterangan" },
        { "data": "sangat_puas" },
        { "data": "puas" },
        { "data": "tidak_puas" },
        { "data": "total" },
        { "data": "nilai" },
    ],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    // Set to 10 results
    "pageLength" : 10,
    // Optional, it'll include '10' in the dropdown menu
    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "paging": true,
});
```

Don't forgot to use the 'draw()' method after making changes to the table - if you don't it won't reflect the changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `iDisplayLength` in your code,

```
"iDisplayLength": 10
```

Here's the [Source](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#iDisplayLength).

So, your source should look like

```
$('#tbl_loket').createTable( {
    "ajax": "<?=site_url('penilaian/report/get_data')?>",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "date_in" },
        { "data": "nama" },
        { "data": "keterangan" },
        { "data": "sangat_puas" },
        { "data": "puas" },
        { "data": "tidak_puas" },
        { "data": "total" },
        { "data": "nilai" },
    ],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "paging": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10
} );
```

Comment: but my table still show 15 items, not 10 items. 

cek this my table screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRrAF.png

Comment: If your library is old, then you shall try `"pageLength": 50
` too

Answer (score 0):

If you want pagination only... just put this code.

```
$("#table_id").DataTable({
    "paging":true,
    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
    "scrollX": true,    
});
```

If you are fetching data form ajax. use this code... 
Make changes according to you

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url         : YOUR_URL,
    data        : {'ids':ids,'start':start, 'end':end},
    timeout     : 30000,
    success     : function (e) {
        $("#table_id").DataTable({
            "paging":true,
            "dom": 'lBfrtip',
            "scrollX": true,    
        });                 
    }       
});
```

One more thing use

```
<?php ?> instead of <?= ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For DataTables version 1.10.5 and newer

```
<table data-page-length='25'>
</table>
```

For DataTables version 1.10 and newer

```
"pageLength": 50
```

For DataTables older than version 1.10

```
"iDisplayLength": 50
```

If all of these don't work, can you please provide the ajax return? Does your ajax return contain recordsFiltered and recordsTotal? It could have the wrong value returned. For example, it is saying showing 1-10 of 15 records, but there are 15 records on page 1, and i assume theres no records on page 2 at all?